Vector representation through untrained fully connected layer
I have a vector as a list, x = [a1,a2,a3,...aN]. I pass it through a fully connected layer defined as this
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')

This fully connected layer is not trained. I am curious to whether the output
output = dense(tf.constant([x]))

would represent the initial vector x in any sort of way despite the untrained dense layer?
I am aware that every time that run
x = [a1,a2,a3,...aN]
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')
output = dense(tf.constant([x]))

the output would be different. However, if I establish the fully connected layer, then pass many vector through the layer, would my outputs be a representation of the vectors I inputed, or random nonsense?

What do you mean by representation of the vectors? (Do you mean output here)?
If kernel_initializer is used then you will get random nonsense only regardless of amounts of layers.
If you use some time of seed for kernel_initializer, then you will get random nonsense still. But random nonsense will be same every time you run. Hope this is answers your query.

Sounds a bit like extreme learning machines. Of course, you can expect different x to be mapped to different hidden outputs. Will this representation be optimal for whatever the task at hand is? Most probably not.
